# Read binary file chunk by chunk into memory buffer in C

Tags: c, tcp, webserver

I have to read a binary file in my webserver and send it to client via TCP. I decided to read it by chunks. How can I do it?

My code with fgets works only with text files (code, that checks return values is omitted):

```
char buf[2048];

fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp);
while (!feof(fp))
{
    Server_TCP_Send(socket, buf, strlen(buf));
    fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp);
}
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: Don't use `fgets` and `strlen` for binary data as they can't handle it (due to embedded nulls in binary data). Use `read` or `fread`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `fread()` instead of `fgets()`, and pay attention to the return value:

```
char buf[2048];
size_t buflen; 

while (1) {
    buflen = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), fp);
    if (buflen < 1) {
        if (!feof(fp)) {
            // a read error occured...
        }
        break;
    }
    Server_TCP_Send(socket, buf, buflen);
}
fclose(fp);
```

Alternatively, some platforms have functions for sending files over a socket.  For example, [`sendfile()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html) on Linux, or [`TransmitFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740565.aspx) on Windows.